# How does one retrieve all values from a specific named column from an array of table row like objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapping

The following variable refers to a table like object structure.

```
const jstable = [{
  "date": "2022-02-08",
  "new_cases": "23100",
  "deaths": "75",
  "recovered": "30294"
}, {
  "date": "2022-03-01",
  "new_cases": "25854",
  "deaths": "78",
  "recovered": "25548"
}];
```

I need to store/push e.g. all values of column `date` into another array. How could this be achieved?

Comment: Does the OP want to retrieve just an explicit column a time? Or is the OP looking for a solution which transforms the above table like structure into a matrix at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through all the elements and get the right attribute.

```js
const jstable = [{"date":"2022-02-08","new_cases":"23100","deaths":"75","recovered":"30294"},{"date":"2022-03-01","new_cases":"25854","deaths":"78","recovered":"25548"}];

function col(array, column){
  let result = [];

  for (let item of array) {
    result.push(item[column]);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(
  col(jstable, 'date')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

And `col(jstable, 'date')` would get you all the `date` column values.

Answer (score 2):

While you can do this with a loop and a collector array, the cleanest way to do it is with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
let dates = jstable.map(row => row.date);
```

---

However, if you need to create arrays for multiple columns, `map` is not the best function to use because it will have to run through the array multiple times, once for each column you are trying to get.

Comment: very elegant and simple, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse(jstable).map(row => row.date);
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: With the question reverted back to its original form (echoing the output of `json_encode`, the `JSON.parse` is unnecessary.

Comment: It's two ways... you can map directly on a json object. If you plan to change the date to another key you can also use

`jstable.map(row => { 
let res = {}; 
res["newDateKey"] = row[row.date];
return res;
})`